# How to display a different text for each image?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem about the foreach instruction and a description for each image. 
Right now, when the user selects an image from the list, the next message occurs (see image1)
What I want is to change this text with a different one for each image.
I've also created a class called WineModel and its code is posted below.
What should I do to display a different description for each image?
One of my ideas would be to create a vector like in this link and to display a different message for each image from the position of the vector.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                WineModel wineModel = new WineModel();
                wineModel.Image = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
                wineModel.Description = file + "Ana are mere" +
                    Environment.NewLine + "text text text text text text text text text text text";
                wineModel.Price = new Random().NextDouble();

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = wineModel.Image;

                bi.EndInit();

                var button = new KinectTileButton
                {
                    Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
                    Tag = wineModel
                };

                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
            }
```

http://i58.tinypic.com/nbvhu8.png
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: You could create an array of strings, each string containing text for a different image in the exact same order as images are sorted in files. Replace for-each loop with for loop and insert image and text of the same index into your code. It's just an idea..

Comment: What i don`t understand is,how can i put an image in this vector?